# How to access the value of a string when defining within a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to access the value of a string when declaring new variables so that I can declare new variables within a loop.

I have tried val(), creating a function. An simplified version of my problem can be found in the code below.

```
Function StudentValue(x As String) As String
   StudentValue = x
End Function


Public Sub TEST()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    Dim n As Integer

    n = 20

    For i = 1 To n
        strName = "Variable" & CStr(i)

        'The problem occurs with the next two lines,
        'once active they create a string with the name 'strName' and not the
        'value of the string eg 'Variable1', 'Variable2', ect

        'Attempt1
        'Dim strName As String
        'Attempt2
        'Dim NameFunction(strName) As String
    Next i

End Sub
```

The errors are as follows:

```
Dim strName As String results in "compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope"

Dim NameFunction(strName) As String results in "compile error: Constant expression required"
```

Is there a function that allows you to access the value of a string when declaring variables?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the point of a function which casts a string to a string? `StudentValue` seems pointless.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. You could store the values and strings in an array, collection or dictionary though.

Comment: Strings don't *have* values, they *are* values.

Comment: I believe this is a [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You think your problem is X but actually you should ask for Y (which is the actual problem). Explain what you are actually trying to do and why you think you need this and we are probably able to suggest you the correct way to do it.

Comment: I am taking Names from a data base and I wish to assign them to a class that I have already created. I hoped to do this through the use of a loop.
1. set the string as the first name in the dataset
2. create a new class entry using that name
3. move on to the next name in the dataset and update the string
4. repeat

I was wondering if there was a way to access the stored value of the string when declaring.

Comment: So when strName is equal to "variable1" I would like 'Dim variable1 as String' rather than 'Dim strName as String'

Comment: The natural solution would be to create a single dictionary which uses those names as keys.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting "Duplicate declaration" Error because you are trying to declare a variable by the same name.
You are getting the error "Constant expression required" Error because Dim XYZ() as string is the syntax for declaring an array.  And the value inside the brackets specifies the size of the array and must be constant.

[Here is a link on how to use arrays.](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html)

Use Option Explicit, it will help you solve problems before they are problems.

Here is your code using arrays.

```
    Option Explicit

    Function StudentValue(x As String) As String
       StudentValue = CStr(x)
    End Function


    Public Sub TEST()
        Const MaxNumNames As Integer = 20

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strNames(1 To MaxNumNames) As String

        For i = 1 To MaxNumNames
            'This will populate the array of names
            strNames(i) = "Variable" & CStr(i)

            'To use the name in the loop
            Debug.Print "In Loop:" & strNames(i)
        Next i

        'To use the name outside the loop (Show 5th name)
        Debug.Print "Outside Loop: " & strNames(5)
        ' To use the name in your function outside the loop (Using 2nd Name)
        Debug.Print "Using Function: " & StudentValue(strNames(2))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Although if you declare a dynamic array, you can `Redim` using the value of `n` (so you don't have to hard-code `20` in 2 different places).

Comment: @zack That's fair.

Comment: @zack redimming for each element you add is more expensive than having a static array, though I guess for a lot of vba scripts the difference will be marginal

Comment: @eirikdaude: I'm not talking about redimming inside the loop, but rather about initially declaring `strNames` as a dynamic array (`Dim strNames() as String`), then redimming to use n: `Redim strNames(1 to n) as String`

Comment: @zack @eirikdaude Updated the code replacing n with a constant, which is used in the array declaration as well as the loop.  Even though we could have used `ubound` and eliminated the need for n altogether.  The reason I didn't do either before was because I wanted to leave the code as close to the original question as possible so he could easily see the significant changes to resolve his question, not necessarily the changes to optimize his code.